# Connect the database

Tags: php, mysqli, database-connection

I try to do the booking form and in the PHP I type the `$stmt->bind_param` part come out syntax error. However, I don't know where I did wrong. Here is my phpMyAdmin setting phpmyadmin table structure:
[image: phpmyadmin table structure]. Below is my code:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$database);

// Check connection

if($conn->connect_error){
        
        die("Connection Failed : ". $conn->connect_error);
    } else {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into event_and_inquiry_form (Name,Mail,Phone_Number,Date,Propose,Person,Theme,Event_Package,Remarks)VALUES (Name, Mail, Phone_Number,Date,Propose,Person,Theme,Event_Package,Remarks);
        
        $stmt->bind_param("sssisisss", $Name,$Mail,$Phone_Number,$Date,$Propose,$Person,$Theme,$Event_Package,$Remarks);
        $execval = $stmt->execute();
        echo $execval;
        $stmt
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    }
```

Comment: Hello to stackoverflow! There is a lonely `$stmt` without a semicolon in the 4th from last line. It helps to read the hint PHP is giving you with the syntax error message, this should also point out the line number.

Answer (score 1):

You do happen to have a few issues.

1. When you prepare your mysqli statement the values to be inserted are to be held by a question mark `?`.  I believe you can hold them with `:name :secondname` as well but that's a story for another question.
2. You have not closed your quotes or bracket on the prepare function.
3. You have a random $stmt variable at the end of your script.

I corrected your code with what I noticed and posted it below:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$database);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `event_and_inquiry_form` 
(`Name`,`Mail`,`Phone_Number`,`Date`,`Propose`,`Person`,`Theme`,`Event_Package`,`Remarks`)
VALUES
( ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?)");

$stmt->bind_param("sssisisss", $Name,$Mail,$Phone_Number,$Date,$Propose,$Person,$Theme,$Event_Package,$Remarks);
$execval = $stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're getting confused between `mysqli` and `PDO` - although there are syntax issues either way!

**mysqli**

With `mysqli` the short answer is that you need to replace all of the variables in `VALUES( ... )` with `?`.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);           // Enable error reporting
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);  // Create connection to database

$sql = "
    INSERT INTO event_and_inquiry_form 
        (Name,Mail,Phone_Number,Date,Propose,Person,Theme,Event_Package,Remarks)
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
";

$query = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param("sssisisss", $Name, $Mail, $Phone_Number, $Date, $Propose, $Person, $Theme, $Event_Package, $Remarks);
$query->execute();
```

**PDO**

You can do it the same way in `PDO`.

Of course the connection method is different and we'll pass an array of the values to the execute function instead.

```
// Connect to the database
$pdo = new pdo(
    "mysql:host={$servername};dbname={$database}",
    $username,
    $password,
    [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE
    ]
);

$sql = "
    INSERT INTO event_and_inquiry_form 
        (Name,Mail,Phone_Number,Date,Propose,Person,Theme,Event_Package,Remarks)
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute([$Name, $Mail, $Phone_Number, $Date, $Propose, $Person, $Theme, $Event_Package, $Remarks]);
```

Finally, in some cases you may prefer to name your placeholders. In this case the name will be `:some_name` and the array will need to be associative `["some_name"=> "Some value"]`.

```
// Connect to the database
$pdo = new pdo(
    "mysql:host={$servername};dbname={$database}",
    $username,
    $password,
    [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE
    ]
);

$sql = "
    INSERT INTO event_and_inquiry_form 
        (Name,Mail,Phone_Number,Date,Propose,Person,Theme,Event_Package,Remarks)
    VALUES
        (:name, :mail, :phone_number, :date, :propose, :person, :theme, :event_package, :remarks)";

$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute([
    "name"          => $Name
    "mail"          => $Mail
    "phone_number"  => $Phone_Number
    "date"          => $Date
    "propose"       => $Propose
    "person"        => $Person
    "theme"         => $Theme
    "event_package" => $Event_Package
    "remarks"       => $Remarks
]);
```